# Very simple Hangman game

Tags: java, game, hangman

Does this code follow standard conventions, not redundant? How I can make it more comprehensible for other people?

It's an exercise from the Java introductory book:

> Write a hangman game that randomly generates a word and
>   prompts the user to guess one letter at a time. Each letter in the word is displayed as an asterisk. When the user makes a correct guess, the actual letter is then displayed. When the user finishes a word, display the number of misses.

My program:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hangman{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] words = {"writer", "that", "program"};
        // Pick random index of words array
        int randomWordNumber = (int) (Math.random() * words.length);
        // Create an array to store already entered letters
        char[] enteredLetters = new char[words[randomWordNumber].length()];
        int triesCount = 0;
        boolean wordIsGuessed = false;
        do {
        // infinitely iterate through cycle as long as enterLetter returns true
        // if enterLetter returns false that means user guessed all the letters
        // in the word e. g. no asterisks were printed by printWord
        switch (enterLetter(words[randomWordNumber], enteredLetters)) {
            case 0:
                triesCount++;
                break;
            case 1:
                triesCount++;
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                wordIsGuessed = true;
                break;
        }
        } while (! wordIsGuessed);
        System.out.println("\nThe word is " + words[randomWordNumber] +
            " You missed " + (triesCount -findEmptyPosition(enteredLetters)) +
            " time(s)");
    }

    /* Hint user to enter a guess letter,
    returns 0 if letter entered is not in the word (counts as try),
    returns 1 if letter were entered 1st time (counts as try),
    returns 2 if already guessed letter was REentered,
    returns 3 if all letters were guessed */
    public static int enterLetter(String word, char[] enteredLetters)    {
        System.out.print("(Guess) Enter a letter in word ");
        // If-clause is true if no asterisks were printed so
        // word is successfully guessed
        if (! printWord(word, enteredLetters))
            return 3;
        System.out.print(" > ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int emptyPosition = findEmptyPosition(enteredLetters);
        char userInput = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
        if (inEnteredLetters(userInput, enteredLetters)) {
            System.out.println(userInput + " is already in the word");
            return 2;
        }
        else if (word.contains(String.valueOf(userInput))) {
            enteredLetters[emptyPosition] = userInput;
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(userInput + " is not in the word");
            return 0;
            }
    }

    /* Print word with asterisks for hidden letters, returns true if
    asterisks were printed, otherwise return false */
    public static boolean printWord(String word, char[] enteredLetters) {
        // Iterate through all letters in word
        boolean asteriskPrinted = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            char letter = word.charAt(i);
            // Check if letter already have been entered bu user before
            if (inEnteredLetters(letter, enteredLetters))
                System.out.print(letter); // If yes - print it
            else {
                System.out.print('*');
                asteriskPrinted = true;
            }
        }
        return asteriskPrinted;
    }

    /* Check if letter is in enteredLetters array */
    public static boolean inEnteredLetters(char letter, char[] enteredLetters) {
        return new String(enteredLetters).contains(String.valueOf(letter));
    }

    /* Find first empty position in array of entered letters (one with code \u0000) */
    public static int findEmptyPosition(char[] enteredLetters) {
        int i = 0;
        while (enteredLetters[i] != '\u0000') i++;
        return i;
    }
}
```

Log of its work:

> ```
> (Guess) Enter a letter in word **** > a
> (Guess) Enter a letter in word **a* > t
> (Guess) Enter a letter in word t*at > q
> q is not in the word
> (Guess) Enter a letter in word t*at > t
> t is already in the word
> (Guess) Enter a letter in word t*at > b
> b is not in the word
> (Guess) Enter a letter in word t*at > h
> (Guess) Enter a letter in word that
> The word is that You missed 2 time(s)
> ```

Comment: Would it be good if I attach link on free-image hosting with image of block-scheme illustrating logic of my program, because it's not obvious how it work or it's not necessary?

Comment: Flowcharts and the like would increase the understandability of what you're doing. That's always a good thing.

Comment: I think you've done a good job removing redundancies and creating methods to make it more concise. It is a little hard to follow, though. Maybe more descriptive method names would help (the best documentation is readable code!)

Comment: your code is too complicated you need to explain what is going on, as it is difficult for a student to read and know exactly what's happening. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magic Numbers: It would be better to move your definitions for 0,1,2,3 into an `enum` or `final` fields so that you can reference them with a meaningful name. For example `final int LETTER_NOT_IN_WORD = 0` or `enum HangmanGuess { LETTER_NOT_IN_WORD }`

Redundancy: The core logic between `findEmptyLetters` and `inEmptyLetters` is the same, you are looking for a `char` in a `char[]`. You could refactor like this:

```
/* Check if letter is in enteredLetters array */
public static boolean inEnteredLetters(char letter, char[] enteredLetters) {
    return indexOf(letter, enteredLetters) >= 0;
}

/* Find first empty position in array of entered letters (one with code \u0000) */
public static int findEmptyPosition(char[] enteredLetters) {
    return indexOf('\u0000', enteredLetters)
}

/* Determine the index in {@code vals} where {@code ch} exists. Returns -1 if {@code ch} is not in {@code vals}. */
public static int indexOf(char ch, char[] vals) { 
    return Arrays.asList(vals).indexOf(Character.valueOf(ch));
}
```

One thing to point out also is that in the current implementation, `findEmptyPosition` will return `n` where `n` is the `enteredLetters.length + 1` if there are no empty positions. I'm not sure if this is the desired functionality.

Answer (score 4):

First (small) thing: it seems more common to use `Random` than `Math.random()`. See [this best practices](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=62) post.

The comments and switch first thing inside the do{ }while() is very confusing for me personally.  `enterLetter()` never returns `true` or `false`, and even most new programmers know a do / while iterates until the condition is met. It would be more helpful to describe what 0-3 represent (and if this were production code or more complex, an Enum would make it considerably more understandable).

Inside of `enterLetter()`, it would be helpful to move the `int emptyPosition = findEmptyPosition(enteredLetters);` call to the `else if` where it's used. Not only does it prevent allocating the memory until it's used, but it's also more readable (and you could remove the `emptyPosition` variable if you wanted and call the function inside the reference, but that's semantic).